# Read from and write to a connection (socket) in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, communication

I'm making a 2d multiplayer game. I made some simple applications using sockets, for example a chatroom. Now I'm trying to implement it to my game with no much success. Maybe I don't understand the loops or the reading and writing correctly? does the reader wait for data if I call a read function?
What I was trying to do: 2 players that can see eachother's positions (and draw a black square there). What I got: the other player is lust jumping around randomly on the screen. (But at least the connection is created)
I tried like this:
Client (not the whole code, just the unsure parts, the connection):

```
class Client {
        private DataInputStream reader;    //I do make these somewhere in my code, these are chained(?) tho the socket
    private DataOutputStream writer;
        int ox, oy;

        private void tick(double delta) {   //logic of the game
        player.move();     //just move the player (client sided)
        try {
            writer.writeInt(ID);      //send player id
            writer.writeInt(player.getX());       //sent the player's x
            writer.writeInt(player.getY());       //same with y
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        class msgReader implements Runnable {      //A new thread for reading the server messages
        public void run() {
            try {
                ID = reader.readInt(); //When the connection is created, player gets an id from server (this actually works) 
                System.out.println(ID);

                while(true) {          //reading loop, maybe this is the wrong part
                    int oid = reader.readInt();  //read an id 
                    if (oid != ID){    //if this is not the player's id
                        ox = reader.readInt();  //store other's x
                        oy = reader.readInt();  //same with y
                    } else {
                        reader.readInt();  //else this is our player
                        reader.readInt();  //so we don't need the data just read it
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The server:

```
public class ServerBase {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    ArrayList clients;  //for the client writers
    private int id = 1;

    class ClientHandler implements Runnable {   //Every client gets a thread
        private Socket soc;
        private DataInputStream reader;
        private DataOutputStream writer;
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int id;

        public ClientHandler(Socket s, DataOutputStream wr) {
            soc = s;
            writer = wr;
            try {
                reader = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true) {   //Maybe this is wrong too, I'm jut unsure of this
                    id = reader.readInt();  //get the id (first thing that player sends)
                    x = reader.readInt();  //same with x and y
                    y = reader.readInt();
                    sendEveryone(id, x, y);  //send everyone the player datas
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void sendEveryone(int a, int b, int c) {
            Iterator it = clients.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()){
                try {
                    DataOutputStream writer = (DataOutputStream) it.next();
                    writer.writeInt(a);
                    writer.writeInt(b);
                    writer.writeInt(c);
                    writer.flush();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void init() {
        clients = new ArrayList();

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5099);

            while(true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();  //wait for a client
                System.out.println("got one");
                DataOutputStream clientWriter = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                clients.add(clientWriter);  
                clientWriter.writeInt(id);
                id++;

                Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket, clientWriter));  //make the thread for the client
                t.start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ServerBase().init();
    }
}
```

Could someone explain what should I do differently? Also is there a more efficent way to send data (in one piece?). How?

Comment: Have a look at `java.util.rmi`, which I use in production, having got into a total tangle with sockets.

Comment: in your `while(true)` are you creating a t thread each time? that lives in the while scope only ?

Comment: does the reader wait for data if I call a read function? Yes. Read blocks.

Comment: No, it lives basically forever. Every client has a thread.

Comment: too much client threads to be created...

Comment: In my example it's just 2. I don't think that's too much.